# Can <table> be a child of <form>?

Tags: html, forms, html-table

Is this valid/good practice?

```
<form action="./" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Enter name:</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-form-element where the content model is defined to be "flow content" which includes "table" (see http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#flow-content-1).

Comment: And yes, if your filling form which is a table, it's the normal way to do it.

Comment: I woud add to your answer that the usage of `<table>` is good practice to format *tabular data*. What is to avoid is implementing layouts other than tables using the `<table>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is always good practice to include elements inside form. In this way you can manage your html web page and also can submit web page data easily by specifying action method in form tag.